# Why does my answer appear to be half-way to being converted into a comment?

Tags: support, comments

I checked back on a question to which I had posted [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83153/36454) and discovered that I allegedly also posted [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83076/tolkien-calls-sauron-morgoths-greatest-servant-but-does-he-ever-really-earn-t#comment179309_83076) with the same content (although truncated) at exactly the same time.

What's going on here? Did a moderator think that my answer should have been a comment, hit the convert button, and then realise that it was truncated and half-undo the conversion? Is it some weird bug?

I would delete the comment, but I don't want to muddy the waters further until I understand what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears a mod converted your post to a comment, then changed his mind and undeleted it, without removing the comment. I can't speak to why he deleted or restored it, but I've deleted the comment as it's incomplete and no longer needed anyway.

Comment: Was it me? I just press buttons at random most of the time.

Comment: @Richard - I'm glad you aren't in control of Strategic Nuclear Weapons

Comment: @dvk - https://33.media.tumblr.com/4385a505104d28d404ffe852e41dd521/tumblr_nd35ospXkl1rqfhi2o1_500.gif

Comment: @Richard - https://shrib.com/Tdo3tQcd (Translation from Russian mine)